# Expose GraphQL schema from non-JS server to a JS client

Tags: javascript, java, graphql, graphql-js

I have a GraphQL server implemented in Java and a JavaScript client querying it. What I don't like is that the client has to just *know* the schema and can not get it from the server instead and dynamically build queries against it.

Now, I understand GraphiQL somehow does just that, but I'm guessing it's because its backend is also written in JavaScript so both the client and server can use it. My schema is defined in Java, but there might be a way to automatically generate a JavaScript representation that the client could use.

Does such a thing already exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, I understand GraphiQL somehow does just that, but I'm guessing it's because its backend is also written in JavaScript so both the client and server can use it.

Actually, (fortunately) this is not the case. It is written in Javascript, but it need not be to achieve this behavior.

I've got some great news for you...

## Introspection!

One of the awesome things about GraphQL is that, in fact, the client doesn't have to know anything about the schema, because it can just query the server for it using **introspection**. In fact, GraphiQL will use this automatically if you don't provide a schema explicitly to automagically populate it.

From the Props section of the [GraphiQL README](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql):

> schema: a GraphQLSchema instance or null if one is not to be used. If undefined is provided, GraphiQL will send an introspection query using the fetcher to produce a schema.

The official [GraphQL Introspection docs](http://graphql.org/docs/introspection/) will give you lot more information and sample queries. Their example of querying their Star Wars example schema:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

This returns the names of all of the types. Introspection is part of the GraphQL spec, so every GraphQL server should be able to do it out of the box: you don't need to explicitly add any functionality.